# Trying to iterate in a linked hashedMap in kotlin but I need a way to compare current and next element with a some value

Tags: loops, dictionary, kotlin

```
   I havent found any method that supports the if clause. Some idea, please?
```

var iterator = map.iterator()

```
   for (iterator in map) {
     if(someValue <= iterator.key && iterator.nextKey >= someValue){
```

do something...}
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the keys in an indexed list and iterate through them:

```
val keys = ArrayList(map.keys)

keys.forEachIndexed { index, key ->
    if (index < keys.size - 1) {
        if (someValue <= key && keys[index + 1] >= someValue) {
            println("$key $index")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one approach could be to use indexed traversal over the entries, like so:

```
    val map = linkedMapOf(
            "A" to "...",
            "B" to "...",
            "C" to "...",
            "D" to "...",
            "F" to "..."
    )

    val entries = map.entries

    entries.forEachIndexed { index, entry ->
        if(index < map.entries.size - 1) {
            if(entry.value == "some-value"
                    && entries.elementAt(index + 1).value == "some-value") {

                // search criteria have been met
            }
        }
    }
```

the `if` statement is of course a check to avoid looking past the end of the list of entries.

Comment: great! please mark the answer as accepted so as to stand out to others who may view this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines:

```
var prevKey: Int? = null
map.forEach { key, _ ->
    if (prevKey != null &&
        (someValue >= prevKey!! && key >= someValue)) {
        // do something
    }
    prevKey = key
}
```

Side note: I assume you wanted to find the pair of keys that `someValue` lies in between. If that's the case, `someValue <= prevKey` in your original question should probably be `someValue >= prevKey`.